# Openid for apps domain

Tags: openid, google-apps

Hi I'm new to openId concepts. I want to use my google apps domain's  user-name & password in third party websites for that i followed this link http://jeremiahlee.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-setup-openid-with-google-apps/. But i got struck on second step i dont know where and how to create openId file in server.Please Help on this issue it will be very useful for me.

Thanks,
Sharun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction is:

> Create a file accessible on your site as http://example.com/openid  with this inside of it:

So you need to put the `openid` file in your `war` directory. (That's what the GAE wizard calls it in eclipse - you may have a different name for your webroot directory.) You'll also need to create a `.htaccess` file in the same place for step 3, and a `.well-known` directory in there too for step 4.